Deactivating a device admin app but button is disabled
I created a device admin app that I have installed for company specific devices but I cannot seem to deactivate it once its installed and enabled as the button is disabled

is there a special manifest permission or something that needs to be added?
doing the command adb shell dpm remove-active-admin does nothing either and I get the error
SecurityException: Attempt to remove non-test admin.
I see other admin apps like Googles Find My Device ass has the button enabled so I am not sure what the difference is.
Any insight would be great

Judging by the description on the screenshot, your device admin is in fact a Device Owner. According to the API documentation :

A device owner app is a special device admin that cannot be deactivated by the user, once activated as a device admin. It also cannot be uninstalled.

The correct way to get rid of it is to wipe the device (if allowed by the said DO)

so then what is the find my device app considered? While it is my app on the device I dont want it to not be able to be deactivated

How would I be able to test/debug updates/new versions if I cant uninstall it to run something from android studio

normal device admin can be (de)activated at anytime by the user. How did you install your app ? Normally a DO can only be installed on the device first boot (or with an dpm set-device-owner  ADB command)

by the way, a DO can be updated, like any other app

For testing purposes I was using the set-device-owner command on a release build on a rooted device. The release version got set as device owner and then I was unable to deactivate/uninstall or run from android studio again. I am not so much concerned about updating a release version of the app just if I need to take a device plug it into debug/test something I wont be able to do that and have to create a release version to update it

a DO can actually deactivate itself with DevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwnerApp() but it is not recommended (and deprecated)

Thats exactly what I was looking for thanks!
